# Calling a c# COM server dll from a C# client app

Tags: c#, dll, com, interop

I got an desktop application which uses a small DLL written in C# registered as an COM object to collect some infos from Active Directory. The app is written in C++, it works fine. I would like to write a small app in C# which would call the same registered DLL's methods (kind of testing tool), but can't figure out how to do this without referencing the COM DLL at compile time (I really need to use the COM registered dll)

[I followed this article](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/com/article.php/c9065/Writing-Your-Own-COM-Interop-in-C.htm), managed to instantiate the object, but i cannot cast the instance to my interface created from IDL. Also the debugger knows the exact type of the instance with all members shown. I suspect this is due the DLL is loaded in the CLR as well.

Is this even possible?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  The IDE will refuse to let you add a reference to the type library.  You can fool it by using late binding.  But that still doesn't fool the CLR, it won't create both a CCW and an RCW.  You'll need a native client, like C++ or a scripting language to truly exercise the COM specific path.

There's just no point, just use the assembly reference directly and use normal C# code to test it.

Answer (score 0):

You can consume a COM component from a C# project. The general steps are as follows:

Locate a COM component to use and register it. Use regsvr32.exe to register or un–register a COM DLL.

Add to the project a reference to the COM component or type library.

When you add the reference, Visual Studio uses the Tlbimp.exe (Type Library Importer), which takes a type library as input, to output a .NET Framework interop assembly. The assembly, also named a runtime callable wrapper (RCW), contains managed classes and interfaces that wrap the COM classes and interfaces that are in the type library. Visual Studio adds to the project a reference to the generated assembly.

Create an instance of a class that is defined in the RCW. This, in turn, creates an instance of the COM object.

Use the object just as you use other managed objects. When the object is reclaimed by garbage collection, the instance of the COM object is also released from memory.

For more information, see Exposing COM Components to the .NET Framework.

Detailed [Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173185.aspx)

Comment: This does not work because the tlbimp.exe refuses to create the CCW for an NET assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the .NET 4.0 `dynamic` type instead of  all the mess of dealing with reflection in that article you mentioned